# Code completion for matplotlib and numpy libraries in qgis script

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, numpy, matplotlib

I would like to know if it's possible to get code completion working for the matplotlib and numpy libraries in QGIS Script.

For example, the following code runs fine in script console of QGIS, but there is no code completion for neither libraries:

[image: Python Code in QGIS Console]

Answer (score 1):

On top of Python console, there is an icon menu item that you can click to open "Settings Python Console" popup box. On the box, there are 2 parts:- console and editor. The defaults for code autocompletion are set to 'ON' with 2 characters threshold. That means it will activate once you type two charaters. Tne minimum for the threshhold you can set is 1. On my machine, both matplotlib and numpy do have code completion.